# country-state-city tools in React

Tags: reactjs, foreach

I'm in trouble again.

I am a complete beginner and sometimes I have difficulties. I'm asking for help.
I am using the react tool: country-state-city.
I want to show the states and then the respective cities, but again I'm having difficulty with the wording.
I'm asking for some help how it should be done.
Here is my code.

```
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import PriceSidebar from './PriceSidebar';
import Stepper from './Stepper';
import { useSnackbar } from 'notistack';
import { saveShippingInfo } from '../../actions/cartAction';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import MetaData from '../Layouts/MetaData';

import { Country, State, City }  from 'country-state-city';
import { ICountry, IState, ICity } from 'country-state-city'

const Shipping = () => {

    const countryCode = 'BG';
    const countries = Country.getCountryByCode(countryCode);
    const states = State.getStatesOfCountry(countries.isoCode);

    const cities = states.forEach((state) => {
       const cities_of_state  = City.getCitiesOfState(countryCode, state.isoCode)
        console.log(cities_of_state)
       
    }, )

    //console.log(states)
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

    const { cartItems } = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
    const { shippingInfo } = useSelector((state) => state.cart);

    const [address, setAddress] = useState(shippingInfo.address);
    
   
    const [state, setState] = useState(countries.isoCode);
    const [city, setCity] = useState(states.isoCode);

    const [pincode, setPincode] = useState(shippingInfo.pincode);
    const [phoneNo, setPhoneNo] = useState(shippingInfo.phoneNo);
    
    const shippingSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (phoneNo.length < 10 || phoneNo.length > 10) {
            enqueueSnackbar("Invalid Phone Number", { variant: "error" });
            return;
        }
        dispatch(saveShippingInfo({ address, city,  state, pincode, phoneNo }));
        navigate("/order/confirm");
    }

    return (
        <>
            <MetaData title="Flipkart: Shipping Details" />
            <main className="w-full mt-20">

                {/* <!-- row --> */}
                <div className="flex flex-col sm:flex-row gap-3.5 w-full sm:w-11/12 mt-0 sm:mt-4 m-auto sm:mb-7 overflow-hidden">

                    {/* <!-- cart column --> */}
                    <div className="flex-1">

                        <Stepper activeStep={1}>
                            <div className="w-full bg-white">

                                <form onSubmit={shippingSubmit} autoComplete="off" className="flex flex-col justify-start gap-3 w-full sm:w-3/4 mx-1 sm:mx-8 my-4">

                                    <TextField
                                        value={address}
                                        onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
                                        fullWidth
                                        label="Address"
                                        variant="outlined"
                                        required
                                    />

                                    <div className="flex gap-6">
                                        <TextField
                                            value={pincode}
                                            onChange={(e) => setPincode(e.target.value)}
                                            type="number"
                                            label="Pincode"
                                            fullWidth
                                            variant="outlined"
                                            required
                                        />
                                        <TextField
                                            value={phoneNo}
                                            onChange={(e) => setPhoneNo(e.target.value)}
                                            type="number"
                                            label="Phone No"
                                            fullWidth
                                            variant="outlined"
                                            required
                                        />
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="flex gap-6">
                                    <FormControl fullWidth >
                                            <InputLabel id="state-select">State</InputLabel>
                                            <Select
                                                labelId="state-select"
                                                id="state-select"
                                                value={state}
                                                label="State"
                                                onChange={(e) => setState(e.target.value)}
                                                required
                                            >
                                                {states.map((state) => (
                                                    <MenuItem key={state.name} value={state.name}>{state.name}</MenuItem>
                                                ))}
                                            </Select>
                                        </FormControl>

                                        <FormControl fullWidth >
                                            <InputLabel id="city-select">City</InputLabel>
                                            <Select
                                                labelId="city-select"
                                                id="city-select"
                                                value={city}
                                                label="City"
                                                onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
                                                required
                                            >
                                                { cities && cities.map((city) => (
                                                    <MenuItem key={city.name} value={city.name}>{city.name}</MenuItem>
                                                ))}
                                            </Select>
                                        </FormControl>
                


                                    </div>

                                    <button type="submit" className="bg-primary-orange w-full sm:w-1/3 my-2 py-3.5 text-sm font-medium text-white shadow hover:shadow-lg rounded-sm uppercase outline-none">save and deliver here</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </Stepper>
                    </div>

                    <PriceSidebar cartItems={cartItems} />
                </div>
            </main>
        </>
    );
};

export default Shipping;
```

"Optional"

Can you also help with API with cities and municipalities in Bulgarian language.

Comment: Can you replicate your issue in `codesandbox`?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-vaughan-ibc8f4?file=/src/App.js